# Movie in which all paper vanishes because of a bacterium

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for an older scifi movie, maybe watched it like 40 years ago(?), in which a bacterium (or similar) eats all paper (books, newspaper, etc.) and tosses humanity close to extinction.

As far as I can remember, in the end scene there is a newspaper blown across an empty space. But I could be mistaken. No idea about main characters. No antidote AFAIR. Pretty sure it was about paper, but maybe it was plastic as well. But for *sure* it was well before internet times.

Comment: But spares all the trees?

Answer (score 14):

The movie I was looking for was actually a German movie: [*Zucker – Eine wirklich süße Katastrophe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zucker_%E2%80%93_Eine_wirklich_s%C3%BC%C3%9Fe_Katastrophe) (1989). The translation is *Sugar - A really Sweet Catastrophe*. It's about cellulose-eating microbes. And it is only 30 years old! An English version does not seem to exist.

> The marriage of the research couple Kaminski is characterized by the fact that one partner wants to be one step ahead of the other in research. Looking for recycling bacteria that will disappear the growing mountains of garbage generated Lydia Kaminski-Smith through genetic manipulation voracious microbes that waste paper and cotton to sugar metabolize can.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware as an ~30k user on SO but you can accept your own answer in roughly 48 hours. Please come back and do so!

Comment: A better translation of the last sentence might be something like, "Looking for recycling bacteria that will eliminate the growing mountains of garbage, Lydia Kaminski-Smith generated voracious microbes through genetic manipulation that can metabolize waste paper and cotton to sugar."

Comment: That's like the real-world research lab that developed a bacterium to decompose vegetal matter farming leftovers into alcohol - just spray the bacterial solution on the harvested field, done. Then they noticed that the bacterium killed all living plants in the experimental setup too because plant roots and alcohol don't mix. I would like to know more about that particular dodged bullet and why there are no bacteria that do such advantageous processing naturally.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer in that particular case, it could be because alcohol and bacteria also do not mix. I imagine that works as an effective self-containment mechanism.